# Can Daxos of Meletis use Ancestral Vision?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Daxos of Meletis](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Daxos%20of%20Meletis) attacked and got through, exiling my [Ancestral Vision](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ancestral%20Vision). Can the player with Daxos use the Ancestral Vision?

From reading through the Gatherer rulings, it seems like even though Daxos of Meletis explicitly says "You may cast that card," because Ancestral Vision has no mana cost, rather than a mana cost of 0, it cannot be cast. It also appears that Suspend is an ability, rather than a alternate cost, therefore Daxos still can't use it.

Is this analysis correct? Can the player with Daxos use Ancestral Vision (in any way)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, you can't suspend or cast Ancestral Vision through Daxos of Meletis.**

The definition for suspend is:

> 702.62a Suspend is a keyword that represents three abilities. The first is a static ability that functions while the card with suspend is in a player’s hand. The second and third are triggered abilities that function in the exile zone. “Suspend N—[cost]” means “If you could begin to cast this card by putting it onto the stack from your hand, you may pay [cost] and exile it with N time counters on it. This action doesn’t use the stack,” [..]

When Daxos triggers, it puts Ancestral Vision into exile, but Suspend only works from your hand. Therefore you can't suspend Ancestral Vision through Daxos.

Also, Daxos specifically allows you to "cast" the exiled card. Suspending a card is a special action and thus something else than casting it.

> 116.2f A player who has a card with suspend in their hand may exile that card. This is a special action. [..]

As for casting, even though Daxos *allows* you to cast AV, you *cannot* cast a card with no mana cost, unless it gained an alternative cost somehow.

> 118.6. Some objects have no mana cost. This represents an unpayable cost. An ability can also have an unpayable cost if its cost is based on the mana cost of an object with no mana cost. Attempting to cast a spell or activate an ability that has an unpayable cost is a legal action. However, attempting to pay an unpayable cost is an illegal action.

To summarize, you can neither suspend Ancestral Vision from exile (where Daxos puts it) nor can you cast it from anywhere.

Comment: I think it would also be good to note "A card with no mana cost can't be cast normally; you'll need a way to cast it for an alternative cost or without paying its mana cost, such as by suspending it." from the ruling

Comment: I'm still slightly confused about that last part. How do you interpret the Golden Rule (where the card text overwrites the rules) with 118.6? Is it the word `may` rather than `can` that makes it an allowance rather than an overwriting?

Comment: @ProQ Norrmally you can cast spells only from your hand. Daxos lifts that specific restriction, allowing you to cast the exiled card from exile. However, all other restrictions to spellcasting still apply. For example, if Daxos exiles a creature card, you may cast that creature from exile, but still only during your main phase and when the stack is empty. As for Ancestral Vision, you may cast it from exile, but you still can't cast it (or, to be precise, you can't pay its mana cost) because it has no mana cost. Daxos doesn't change that fact or lift that restriction.